# Pandas: create a 3 levels multiindex using row information

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe. Note I use the "" to spot the column header

```
"col1"   "col2"   "col3"
 name     last      age
 ger      ger1      ger2
 Xccc     123       75.7
```

The columns headers of this df are col1, col2, col3. I want to have a multiindex in 3 levels.

Level 0: col1, col2, col3
Level 1: name, last, age
Level 3: ger, ger1, ger2

THis way the dataframe printed should be like this:

```
"col1"   "col2"    "col3"
"name"   "last"    "age"
"ger"    "ger1"    "ger2"
 Xccc     123       75.7
```

How could I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[:2].T.reset_index()).rename([0,1,2])
pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[2:].values, columns=cols)
```

[image]

---

1. First step creates the first 2 rows + existing columns as multi-indexes using `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame()`
2. The `.rename` lets you name the levels.
3. Second step takes the remaining rows (after 2) and creates a new data frame with these multi-index columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.T.set_index([df.T.index, 0, 1]).T
print(df)

   col1 col2  col3
0  name last   age
1   ger ger1  ger2
2  Xccc  123  75.7

print(df.columns)

MultiIndex([('col1', 'name',  'ger'),
            ('col2', 'last', 'ger1'),
            ('col3',  'age', 'ger2')],
           names=[None, 0, 1])
```